# communication between components - code emitter not working in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 2. I want to catch value between 2 component. It serves for spinner I write ApiService.ts. It declare function common for method get,post,..

After using emitter in fuction ngOnInit(){}, It works very well.

But I write in function apiGet(){}. It's function common for method get. But using emitter in it, It not working ? Any solution?
This is image apiSerice.ts [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5ZIC.png)

This is image public.component.ts [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UHV9.png)

Html public.component.ts:

```html
<api (isLoading)='fIsLoading($event)'></api>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: How did you called `apiGet` method of your component?

Comment: ex: I write function get data in productComponent.ts, I using common service "apiGet". When call function get data, it returns the data but emmit not working

Comment: Strange, any error in console?

Comment: No error. It dont catch event emitter